# Maven assembly plugin without separate descriptor xml file

Tags: maven

I have a `pom` file with `assembly` plugin which uses

```
<descriptor>src/main/assembly/dist.xml</descriptor>
```

Is there any way I can add the information in `dist.xml` directly in the `pom` file and have only one file for Maven?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what is present in `dist.xml`.  If your assembly can be built with [predefined descriptors](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html) and the configurations provided by the [goal](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html) is sufficient, then you do not need a separate `descriptor` file.

The [usage](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html) page of the maven assembly plugin has a few examples which show how it can be done.

Comment: I don't see any example which can specify the `assembly` tag or specify the `format`.

Comment: @ATOzTOA That is because there are no configuration goals for these. Take a look at the [predefined descriptors](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html) - they have these tags with the appropriate values

Comment: But, for predefined descriptors, I cannot change anything, right?

Answer (score 1):

First the [descriptor](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html#descriptor) is marked as deprecated you should use [descriptors](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html#descriptors) instead. And no there is no possibility to define the descriptor within the pom.

Comment: What is the delimiter for the descriptor files?

Comment: What do you mean by delimiter?

Comment: How do I specify more than one `descriptor` file?